# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.<init>(Lcom/sun/jersey/core/spi/component/ProviderServices;)V

Tags: java, web-services, maven, jboss, jersey

I am trying to deploy a maven build Java project to JBoss server web project. I am able to reach the desired server. However, I could not get the intended reply back from server. The error comes up as :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.<init>(Lcom/sun/jersey/core/spi/component/ProviderServices;)V
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:230)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:158)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(Client.java:573)
```

I have jerser-core 1.2, jersey-bundle 1.2, jersey-server 1.2, jersey-client 1.2, jersey servlet 1.17, and jersey

```
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:230)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:158)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(Client.java:573)
```

1.17 in my lib folder.

Comment: The error msg clearly says there is a old version of jerser-core 1.2 jars loaded in the class loader.

Comment: Try using common version for all the jersey dependency jars

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/4266592/32453

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there is something wrong with tha jars in your classpath. Probably, you may have two different versions of jersey on your classpath or in WEB-INF/lib